# Is document.write(window.location.hash.substr(1)) still exploitable for DOM XSS?

Tags: xss, javascript, vulnerability, dom

I stumbled upon Google's firing range for DOM XSS testing, and [this](https://public-firing-range.appspot.com/address/location.hash/documentwrite) case caught my eye:

```
<script>
  var payload = window.location.hash.substr(1);document.write(payload);
</script>
```

As far as I know, Chrome, Firefox ans Safari now URL-encode `location.hash` and `location.search`, making the exploit fail:

malicious link:

```
https://public-firing-range.appspot.com/address/location.hash/documentwrite#<script>alert(1)</script>
```

result on page:

```
%3Cscript%3Ealert(1)%3C/script%3E
```

Given that the above-mentioned browsers take up most of the market share, is this vulnerability effectively not exploitable anymore? Or is there a way to exploit it despite the URL-encoding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If they are just _most_ of the market share, doesn't that mean there are still browsers out there that are still vulnerable?

Comment: @dandavis, the script snippet is not under the attacker's control, only the URL. I agree that naming the variable as 'payload' is a bit confusing.

Comment: @FireQuacker fair enough. I think IE browsers and Microsoft Edge don't URL-encode `location.hash` so they are definitely still vulnerable.